# Google drive для тестов

Tags: java, android

Настроил google drive в приложении андроид по гугловой документации, но она работает только если загружать приложение с маркета, у меня сделано в бета, но google drive не работает если устанавлить приложение в телефон с android studio, как можно сделать чтобы соединение работало и в android studio

Comment: подскажите как можно добавить фингерпринт в дебаг сертификат?

Comment: Добавил сертификат с которым он билдит apk в Project Structure - Signing но это не помогло.

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20where%20is%20debug%20keystore&es_th=1

Comment: да не правильно понял вас изначально, спасибо, добавил отпечаток сертификата для developer console сейчас работает

Comment: @metalurgus, оформите как ответ первый комментарий, если не затруднит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

думаю, что дело в сертификате, которым подписывается приложение. Ведь нужно же куда-нибудь добавлять фингерпринт своего сертификата? Если да, то добавьте туда же и фингерпринт debug сертификата